# Автовывод текста или кода с textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно чтобы когда я вводил текст в textarea он сразу же выводился ниже без submit.

Например, я ввожу `<p align='center'>text</p>` и ниже выводит `text` по середине, а не код.

Comment: А причем тут `ajax`? https://jsfiddle.net/m49j27zc/

Comment: как сделать что бы выводил код тоесть я ввожу <p align='center'>text</p> и выводит текст по середине а не код

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
<form>
    <textarea id="input_text"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="output_text"></div>
<script>
    var input_text = document.getElementById('input_text');
    var output_text = document.getElementById('output_text');
    input_text.onkeyup = function () {
        output_text.innerHTML = input_text.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо то что надо!